# SQL Server : case multiple operations in then part

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I have this case as a part of a bigger SQL statement:

```
.
.
.
CASE    
   WHEN [AEC].item = 'S' THEN [sOld].code
   WHEN [AEC].item= 'R' THEN [rOld].code
END AS [oldCode],

CASE    
   WHEN [AEC].item= 'S' THEN [sOld].system
   WHEN [AEC].item= 'R' THEN [rOld].system
END AS [oldStatusSystem],

CASE    
   WHEN [AEC].item= 'S' THEN [sNew].code
   WHEN [AEC].item= 'R' THEN [rNew].code
END AS [newCode],

CASE     
   WHEN [AEC].item= 'S' THEN [sNew].system
   WHEN [AEC].item= 'R' THEN [rNew].system
END AS [newStatusSystem],
.
.

LEFT JOIN 
    tblSystemStatuses AS [sOld] ON [AEC].oldValue = [sOld].status
LEFT JOIN
    tblSystemStatuses AS [sNew] ON [AEC].newValue = [sNew].status
LEFT JOIN
    tblSystemRoles AS [rOld] ON [AEC].oldValue = [rOld].role
LEFT JOIN
    tblSystemRoles AS [rNew] ON [AEC].newValue = [rNew].role
```

What I would like the case to look like is something like:

```
CASE    
   WHEN [AEC].item = 'S' 
      THEN 
           [sOld].code AS [oldCode],
           [sOld].system AS [oldStatusSystem],
           [sNew].code AS [newCode], 
           [sNew].system AS [newStatusSystem]
   ELSE WHEN [AEC].item = 'R' 
      THEN 
           [rOld].code AS [oldCode],
           [rOld].system AS [oldStatusSystem],
           [rNew].code AS [newCode], 
           [rNew].system AS [newStatusSystem]
  END
```

In another words I would like to perform few operations as a part of then statement. I could not see an example anywhere for that.

I can't write if else because I need to make some joins and rely on data from several tables. Is there a way to write the case in the way I would like?

Comment: I don't think it's possible as case is a function that 'returns' something, if you're coding on NPP or SSMS you can write the same on multiple rows with vertical selection:  keeping pressed alt+shift

Comment: Nope. Case is an expression and it returns a scalar value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to rewrite this one and more readable one is

```
.
.
.
ISNULL([sOld].code, [rOld].code) AS [oldCode],
ISNULL([sOld].system, [rOld].system) AS [oldStatusSystem],
ISNULL([sNew].code, [rNew].code) AS [newCode],
ISNULL([sNew].system, [rNew].system) AS [newStatusSystem],
.
.
.
LEFT JOIN tblSystemStatuses  AS [sOld]
    ON [AEC].oldValue = [sOld].status
    AND [AEC].item = 's'
LEFT JOIN tblSystemStatuses 
    ON [AEC].newValue = [sNew].status
    AND [AEC].item = 's'
LEFT JOIN tblSystemRoles 
    ON [AEC].oldValue = [rOld].role
    AND [AEC].item = 'r'
LEFT JOIN tblSystemRoles 
    ON [AEC].newValue = [rNew].role
    AND [AEC].item = 'r'
```

Answer (score 5):

A `case` expression only returns a single value.  So, you cannot do what you want.

You can simplify the logic, but in a slightly different way. Probably the best approach is to use `cross apply`.  Note that this goes in the `from` clause, because expressions in the `select` can only return scalar values.  So, you need to select the columns you want in the select:

```
select v.oldcode, . . . 
from . . . cross apply
     (select v.*
      from (values ('S', [sOld].code, [sOld].system, [sNew].code, [sNew].system),
                   ('R', [rOld].code, [rOld].system, [rNew].code, [rNew].system)
           ) v(item, oldcode, oldsystem, newcode, newsystem)
      where v.item = [AEC].item
     ) v
```

This meets the same needs as the what you want with a single `case` expression.  Notably, the matching logic only appears once.  This version has the advantage that the individual fields can be used in more than one expression in the `select`.

Comment: @Polina . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?  You had already accepted it and it seems simpler than a bunch of `left join`s.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with a way of doing it with `CASE EXPRESSION`, but you can use `UNION` :

```
SELECT [sOld].code as [oldCode],
       [sOld].system as [oldStatusSystem],
       [sNew].code as [newCode], 
       [sNew].system as [newStatusSystem]
FROM ...
WHERE [AEC].item = 's' 
UNION ALL 
SELECT [rOld].code as [oldCode],
       [rOld].system as [oldStatusSystem],
       [rNew].code as [newCode], 
       [rNew].system as [newStatusSystem]
FROM ...
WHERE [AEC].item = 'r'
```